# multiple Authorization in same folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, authorization

As a test, I have created an empty c# web application.
then I created 5 empty pages in the same folder(directly under webApplication folder):
WebForm1.aspx
WebForm2.aspx
WebForm3.aspx
WebForm4.aspx
login.aspx

after that I tried to limit access to some of these pages.

WebForm1, WebForm2 should be access by all (Anonymous users) 
WebForm3 must be access by only authenticated users.
WebForm4 must be access by only admins.

so I modified web.config file to be like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <authentication>
      <forms defaultUrl="WebForm1.aspx" loginUrl="login.aspx"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

  <location path="WebForm3.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authentication></authentication>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="WebForm4.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authentication></authentication>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admins"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

now all users can access WebForm1 and WebForm2 (public pages)
but trying to browse WebForm3.aspx or WebForm4.aspx displays error, and does not redirect to login page first for admin.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:


Line 18:   <location path="WebForm3.aspx">
Line 19:     <system.web>
Line 20:       <authentication></authentication>
Line 21:       <authorization>
Line 22:         <allow users="*"/>


Source File: E:\testApp\testApp\web.config    Line: 20

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34280
```

how to control accessing all pages with kipping them in the same folder? the real application structure is similar to this one.

Comment: What happens when you add this  <forms defaultUrl="WebForm1.aspx" loginUrl="login.aspx"></forms> in the authentication tag.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`<authentication>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) documentation.

> This element can be declared only at the machine, site, or application level. Any attempt to declare it in a configuration file at the subdirectory or page level will result in a parser error message.

Removing these from your `<location>` tags should get it working again.

```
<location path="WebForm3.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>

<location path="WebForm4.aspx">
  <system.web>       
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="admins"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```